# Adding SK3DNode Crashes app on iPhone 5s or higher

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, scenekit

I'm trying to add a 3D model to a SpriteKit project, but it's crashing immediately with very little debug info [edit: just on iPhone 5s or higher, iPhone 5 or lower works fine!] and I'm not sure what is going on.

I start with the SpriteKit default project in Xcode, and copy in the ship.dae file from the Xcode default SceneKit project.

Here is my code for creating and adding the `SK3DNode`:

```
SK3DNode *shipNode = [[SK3DNode alloc] initWithViewportSize:CGSizeMake(30, 30)];
SCNScene *shipScene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"ship.dae"];
[shipNode setPosition:CGPointMake(self.size.width/2,self.size.height/2)];
[shipNode setScnScene:shipScene];
[self addChild:shipNode];
```

When this project is run it immediately crashes with:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x174)

If I comment out either `addChild:` or `setPosition:`, then it does not crash, but the model does not appear, either.

Any ideas?

Comment: At what line does it crash and what is the detailed error message (not just EXC...)

Comment: That's the thing that is so weird... the debug output has no error message at all. The debug output area only has "(lldb)".

If I put in a breakpoint and step through line by line until it crashes, it is actually crashing at [skView presentScene:scene]; in the GameViewController.m file.

When it does crash, it jumps back to the return line in main( ), and gives me the bad access error.

Comment: did you try letting the program continue? sometimes it just encounters an error and halts the program and you need to resume the program to actually get the error message!?

Comment: It's dumping, so there's no way to continue AFAIK. Hitting the continue button in the debugger just restarts the app from the top and jumps to the dump again.

Comment: hmm, i sadly dont know what might be wrong :/

Comment: Grr. Apple's sample code from WWDC crashes too. Page 110 of "What's New in SpriteKit" 

http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/606xxql3qoibema/606/606_whats_new_in_sprite_kit.pdf?dl=1

Comment: A found another odd behavior: it works just fine if I set the simulator device to iPhone 5 or lower. 5s or above crashes as described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug somewhere in the 64-bit code or compiler that does not exist in the 32-bit code.

Changing the Architecture settings within Build Settings to `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)` fixes the crash on all devices.

I'll leave it like that for now and hope a better solution or fix comes along...

Comment: I found an alternate solution, add this code after initializing the SK3DNode:

`id s1 = [sk3DNodeFist valueForKey:@"_scnRenderer"];
    NSLog(@"%@", s1);`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the scene renderer needs to be initialized. This code fixes it; note that the NSLog statement is required, without it, the app still crashes.

```
id s1 = [sk3DNodeFist valueForKey:@"_scnRenderer"]; 
NSLog(@"%@", s1);
```